# How do you delete a database cartridge on an Openshift app?

Tags: database, postgresql, openshift

I added a PostgreSQL 9.2 database on my Openshift hosted Python/Flask app but now I don't think it will be needed. Is there an easy way to just remove this cartridge from the application?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `rhc` tool to remove a cartridge:

`rhc cartridge remove -a {appName} -c {embeddedCartridgeName}`

Comment: I've ssh'd into my account from terminal on Ubuntu but it won't recognize rhc cartridge as a command.

Comment: @LuísSoares First you read the documentation: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/common-rhc-commands.html Then run `rhc cartridge-list`

Comment: thanks for the great tip! in fact, that was my tip to get the answer a bit more complete.